# How to join different array value from looping result in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have array in here but I still confused how can I join my all array result from looping, from json I have data like this :

```
{
   "getFruit": [
       {
          "id": 1,
          "name_of_fruit": Apple,
          "price": 40000,
       },
       {
          "id": 2,
          "name_of_fruit": Orange,
          "price": 45000,
       },
       {
          "id": 3,
          "name_of_fruit": Grape,
          "price": 50000,
       },
    ]
}
```

When I manipulation my data with for looping the result to be like this :

```
for (let i = 0; i < getFruit.length; i++) {
   console.log(getFruit[i]);
}

// result in console
{"id": 1,"name_of_fruit": Apple,"price": 40000}
{"id": 2,"name_of_fruit": Orange,"price": 45000}
{"id": 3,"name_of_fruit": Grape,"price": 50000}
```

And for the question is how to join value in field `name_of_fruit`, `price`, and make my value into the string value? I make like this and it's doesnt work :

```
for (let i = 0; i < getFruit.length; i++) {
   let a = getFruit[i]['name_of_fruit'];
   let b = getFruit[i]['price'];
   console.log(a, b);
}

// result in console
Apple 40000
Orange 45000
Grape 50000

// expectation result that I want
[Apple - 40000, Orange - 45000, Grape - 50000] <= this result I wanna insert into the input value in my HTML
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `getFruit.map((fruit) => \`${fruit.name_of_fruit} - ${fruit.price}\`)`

Comment: not yet, thanks for your advice, I'll try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `getFruit` array into an array of strings in the format you want.

Then set that into your `<input>` via [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const obj = {"getFruit":[{"id":1,"name_of_fruit":"Apple","price":40000},{"id":2,"name_of_fruit":"Orange","price":45000},{"id":3,"name_of_fruit":"Grape","price":50000}]}

const formatted = obj.getFruit.map(({ name_of_fruit, price }) =>
  `${name_of_fruit} - ${price}`)
  
document.querySelector("input#whatever").value = `[${formatted.join(", ")}]`
```

```html
<input id="whatever" size="50">
```

Comment: first think I wanna say thank to you, so I must use map() function first to create new array again, and then insert them into the input value right?

Comment: @LuckALip To explain the idea, you have an array of objects, You need to get specific values. So you create another array that has these values to make sure you do not override existing array and have both values handy to do your processing

Comment: means, suppose I create an empty array to accommodate the data that I have previously and I enter each value into a new array, is it really like that?

Comment: @LuckALip `Array.prototye.map()` takes each entry in an array (your _fruit_ objects) and returns a new value (in this case the formatted string) which it builds into a new array

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < getFruit.length; i++) {
   let a = getFruit[i]['name_of_fruit'];
   let b = getFruit[i]['price'];
   arr.push(a + ' - ' + b);
}
let result = '[' + arr.join(', ') + ']';
console.log(result);
```

Or you can use

```
let result = getFruit.reduce((a, b) => [ !a ? '' : a + ', ', b.name_of_fruit, ' - ', b.price].join(''), '');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an Object and push whatever you need inside it.

```
let array = {};
for (let i = 0; i < getFruit.length; i++) {
   let a = getFruit[i]['name_of_fruit'];
   let b = getFruit[i]['price'];
   array[a] = b;
}
//Now, the result would be
//{Apple: 40000, Orange: 45000, Grape: 50000}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to the answers provided already would be to make a string and continually concatenate to the string. Like this:

```
var finalInfo = "[";
for (let i = 0; i < getFruit.length; i++) {
   let a = getFruit[i]['name_of_fruit'];
   let b = getFruit[i]['price'];
   if(i != 0){
   // A comma will be added to the beginning of all iterations except the first
      finalInfo += ", ";
   }
   finalInfo += a + " - " + b;
   
}
finalInfo += "]";
```